# How to remove indirect left recursion in Antlr grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4, left-recursion

I've a grammar as follow:

```
expression : scalar 
           | vector;
scalar : <bunch of rules>
       | vector[scalar] #VectorIndex
       ;
vector : <bunch of rules>
       | scalar ('*' | '+' | '-') vector
       ;
```

Is there any possibility to remove indirect left recursion from this grammar? Replacing `vector` with all its sub-rules will make the grammar too repetitive and messy.

Comment: You should just merge the `vector` and `scalar` rules into a single `expression` rule and let the type checker take care of the distinction between vectors and scalars.

Comment: If I do that I'll have all the `vector` rules twice - once when I merge `vector` into `expression` and once for the `scalar` rule `vector[scalar]`.

Comment: `vector[scala]` would just become `expression[expression]`.

Comment: It'll make the grammar more flexible than desired - I don't want to accept something like `vector[vector]`. How do you suggest we can handle that?

Comment: As I said, that'd be the type checker's job (or the runtime system's in a dynamically typed language)

Comment: What do you mean type checker in Antlr? You mean add checks in the visitor?

Comment: A type checker is the phase of the compiler that rejects programs if they contain type errors. And yes, that would usually be implemented as a visitor.